# How can I use ASP .NET Webforms view engine in a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have searched and cannot find any specifics or examples, but I have to use .NET 3.5 so I believe I am stuck with the webforms view engine.  So does any have any examples or information on how to use the webfroms view engine in a class library for the purpose of a template system?

Comment: use model classes in your mvc project.

Comment: there are 10 better templating engines for .net than web forms - NVelocity comes first to mind.

Comment: This view engine is not designed to be used as a templating system outside of a hosted environment.

Comment: I totally agree but I am restricted to only items in that are Microsoft only.  Others have shown examples using Razor in this way.

Comment: @Jamie Razor is also microsoft. Your question is a little bit vague. Do you need asp.net webforms engine as a templating engine ? you cannot use any opensource lightweight libraries ?

Comment: Yes, I need ASP .NET Webforms view engine as a template engine as I cannot use any non-microsoft libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you need to host and execute ASP.NET pages without a web server. It is possible and well described by Jim Klopfenstein in his [Executing ASPX pages without a web server](http://radio-weblogs.com/0105476/stories/2002/07/12/executingAspxPagesWithoutAWebServer.html)  blog post.

Generally speaking all work is done by following classes:

- [HttpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.processrequest%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [HttpWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [HttpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Here is snippet from mentioned above post (resulting HTML will be printed to the console):

```
void ProcessRequest(String page)
{
    HttpWorkerRequest hwr = new SimpleWorkerRequest(page, null, Console.Out);
    HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(hwr);
}
```